# how to activate the OSGi console in web.xml with an example

Tags: jboss, eclipse-plugin, osgi

can any body tell me how one should activate Osgi console in web.xml when one is tried to deploy .war?

Please provide one example

Any help would appreciate.

:)

Comment: I want to activate osgi console when I deploy my application from server.

Comment: 1) What server?  2) By OSGi console do you mean the interactive shell?  3) As Fredrik says, 7 questions some of which have extensive answers and you don't accept any - why don't you accept correct answers? (click the big tick by answer)

Comment: here is the scenario:
I am deploying my RAP application(i.e. .war file) into JBOSS server and i uncommented following lines in web.xml 
<init-param>
   <param-name>commandline</param-name>
   <param-value>-console 2402</param-value>   
  </init-param> now i want to check OSGi console
and i did telnet localhost 2402 but not able to open console can you please tell me what is missing here

Comment: Hi Mum, sorry I don't know too much about JBoss, I've retagged your question so hopefully some JBoss experts will be able to help you.  From what I can see JBoss is using lots of Felix components, try setting the properties from here http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-remote-shell.html as system properties for JBoss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that only the last `<init-param>` element is used. So if you have additional `<init-param>` elements - e.g. for `-registryMultiLanguage` or similar - then these must be merged into a single element.

Also note that the Java EE server is *not* required to start the OSGi container before the first request... Tomcat does start it as it is started itself, but I don't know about JBoss.